# This script is messing up

Tags: lua, roblox

When I load into the game when I click 5 times it disappears but doesn't show the image label.
Please help!

```
local hits = 0
local model = script.Parent.Parent

game.StarterGui.Inventory.ImageLabel.Visible = false

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    hits = hits + 1
    if hits > 4 then
        model.Union.Transparency = 1
        model.Union.CanCollide = false
        model.Part1.Transparency = 1
        model.Part1.CanCollide = false
        model.Part2.Transparency = 1
        model.Part2.CanCollide = false
        model.Part3.Transparency = 1
        model.Part3.CanCollide = false
        model.Part4.Transparency = 1
        model.Part4.CanCollide = false
        game.StarterGui.Inventory.ImageLabel.Visible = true
        wait(1)
        game.StarterGui.Inventory.ImageLabel.Visible = false
    end
end)
```

Comment: if you start with `game.StarterGui.Inventory.ImageLabel.Visible` set to `true` is it visible until after you click 5 times?

Comment: No, because what I'm trying to do is make a new version of booga booga. I'm trying to make it show when you mine it, it will show a image of the iron ore and then after 1 second it will disappear! @Nifim

Comment: I understand that, my question/suggestion is to check if the image even works. by setting it to true initially you should see the image if it you don't you now have more information about what is wrong if you do and than proceed to click 5 times and it does not disappear, again more information about what specifically does not work.

Comment: How do I fix it? @Nifim

Comment: Use GetService. Also try waitforchild instead of directly referencing variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set visibility of the gui inside the player's PlayerGui. StarterGui is the service that provides the gui for players when they spawn in.

```lua
local hits = 0
local model = script.Parent.Parent
local imageLabel = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui"):WaitForChild("Inventory"):WaitForChild("ImageLabel")

imageLabel.Visible = false

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    hits = hits + 1
    if hits > 4 then
        model.Union.Transparency = 1
        model.Union.CanCollide = false
        model.Part1.Transparency = 1
        model.Part1.CanCollide = false
        model.Part2.Transparency = 1
        model.Part2.CanCollide = false
        model.Part3.Transparency = 1
        model.Part3.CanCollide = false
        model.Part4.Transparency = 1
        model.Part4.CanCollide = false
        imageLabel.Visible = true
        wait(1)
        imageLabel.Visible = false
    end
end)
```